# How to make std::regex begin matching at a specific position in a string?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

C#'s [`Regex.Match` method has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx) that allows the matching to begin at a specific offset.

How can I make `std::regex` begin matching at a specified position in the string?

#### Note regarding the naive solution:

No, I **cannot** just pass a substring starting at that position -- the prefix might change things.

For example, the prefix may indicate that the given position is *not* the beginning of a new line, whereas if I chopped off the string, it would appear like a new line and I would get an incorrect match for patterns that need to detect newlines. The same problem exists for lookbehinds and such.

Comment: It takes an iterator range – why not just pass in `begin(str) + N` for the first iterator?

Comment: @ildjarn: lol, did you even read the part of my question that I specifically bolded?

Comment: Yes, I did. Incrementing the first iterator does not create a substring – `std::string::substr` does that. What I suggested is semantically identical to the `Regex.Match` overload you linked to.

Comment: @ildjarn: How is passing an actual substring any different from passing an iterator range that denotes a substring? I'm confused.

Comment: One creates a new string, the other doesn't...

Comment: @ildjarn: Uhm what?! How is the regex constructor supposed to tell the difference?! By decrementing the begin iterator and "peeking" behind it?!

Comment: Why should it care about any difference? It's iterator-based... Again, what I suggested is semantically _identical_ to the `Regex.Match` overload you linked to: starts at a specific index into an existing string, without creating a new string.

Comment: @ildjarn: *"Why should it care about the difference?"* Read my question again, I explained it there. There's a huge difference. The problem isn't whether or not it's a new string in C++ terms, the problem is that what comes **before** the input can affect the matching of the input.

Comment: Then you shouldn't link to that `Regex.Match` overload, since _it_ does what I'm suggesting. Meh, -1 for a confusing question.

Comment: @ildjarn: Jeezus, would you mind you taking back the -1 please? I'm spending time trying to explain it to you and you give up and -1?! If I wasn't willing to clarify things then I wouldn't have responded here..

Comment: You didn't explain anything, you just said to read the question which I've already read.

Comment: @ildjarn: Sigh, here's another try. Can you tell the difference between `Regex.Match(s, i)` and `Regex.Match(s.Substring(i))`, aside from the irrelevant heap allocation? It's the exact same problem here -- they don't necessarily return the same results because lookbehinds available in the string can influence the results. As another example: in fact, the `Regex.Match(s, i, n)` overload is equivalent to `Regex.Match(s.Substring(i, n))` but it is **not** equivalent to `Regex.Match(s.Substring(s.Length - i), i)`. Confusing if you don't know it already, yes, but that's why I'm explaining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that you would want to use the match flag to specify that the iterator is part of a larger string.

You would need to use an iterator that has been advanced as @ildjarn suggested, and then use the flag `std::regex_constants::match_prev_avail` which specifies that the iterator `--first` is dereferencable.  This will allow the regular expression matcher to use the immediately previous element as part of its testing.

Comment: Ooooh awesome, I'll try that, thanks! +1 What happens with lookbehinds of > 1 char btw? Is that also allowed?

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm not certain, as I've not really done anything with that flag.  I would recommend using the documention for Boost Regex http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html which was used as a basis for the `std::regex`.  However, in this case, I strongly suspect that anything other than checking the single previous character will not work.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working... am I missing something? When I try `string a = "ab"; cout << regex_match(a.begin() + 1, a.end(), sregex::compile("^b"), match_prev_avail);` (which is intended to only match strings that begin with a line that begins with `b`) I get back `1` instead of `0`. Ideas?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I would check the compiler/library version.  If I use the boost version (I don't have a compiler that supports the C++11 version on hand at the moment), it works and prints '0'.  I've put a copy of the code at http://ideone.com/AxxKcl (though it won't compile there, since IDEOne doesn't have boost regex)

Comment: Also, unless you've defined it, `sregex` isn't a normal Standard Library type.  The library defines `std::basic_regex<T, Traits>`, and defines `typedef basic_regex<char> regex`.  And, it doesn't define a `compile` method.

Comment: Oh shoot, I tested it with `boost::xpressive`, not with `std::regex`! Seems like I found a bug in Xpressive then! [It works fine for `std::regex`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/q9NC1$1); thanks!

Comment: Wait, actually, seems like `<regex>` (the C++11 one) is broken in a different way -- [`regex_match("b", std::regex("^b"))` doesn't output 1 either](http://liveworkspace.org/code/q9NC1$8).

Comment: @Mehrdad: GCC Standard library has not fully implemented `regex` yet See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x  It's why I used the boost version for now.  I believe CLang's is more complete